# Would adding an int-hash column to small-ish char/binary column improve retrieval performance?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

This is a question about the tradeoffs in storage and retrieval: we have a schema that includes a SHA256 (64 byte ascii/32 byte binary) as a primary key.
I've been looking into the storage characteristics of medium(-ish) strings on both mysql and postgresql and it's been interesting but so far inconclusive.

Our patterns are write-once, read-by-key many, no range/ordered reads.

What I'm pondering is whether it would make sense to add a 32 or 64 bit int as a prefix to the primary key to restructure the first level of index. Since this is a SHA, we can just use the first or last bits of the SHA (since the SHA should be uniformly distributed).

We can test it but coming up with meaningful tests is challenging (easy to get some data, challenging to get statistically relevant data).

Any insight/recommendation/references to the dynamics of this?

Answer (score 0):

While hashing isn't a bad idea per-se, you'd need a very convincing benchmark to show why it's worth inventing your own mechanism (and handling the administrative overhead) instead of letting the database do the heavy lifting for you.

Most databases already have similar built-in features, such as [hash indexes in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/indexes-types.html#id-1.5.10.5.6.1) or [hash indexes in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-btree-hash.html#hash-index-characteristics).

Comment: Hrm ... sounds like the idea would be just get the db to use a hashed index and you get the same/better benefit of adding the int column and using a btree index ... which makes a lot of sense (and removes potential consistency errors). In a quick scan yesterday I saw something that said innodb didn't actually do hashed indexes but that looks out of date ...